# I Really Can't find Recycle Viewer in Android Support Libraries

Tags: android, android-library

I want to use `RecyclerView` in my project but I can't import it.
I added to gradle:

compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1' in my project

what should i do?

in gradle:app

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'}
```

and under my package i imported:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
```

It can't resolve symble "RecyclerView"

Comment: And why you don't use the latest version ? 23.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1' in gradle

And update your sdk

targetSdkVersion 23

Now it will support.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your app build.gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
```

your targetSDKVersion to 23

and paste this code in your layout file

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```